# How to add Ubuntu to the Windows XP boot.ini file?

Tags: dual-boot, 12.04, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to boot Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 Alpha 2 on a partition separate partition from Windows and was wanting to know how to add the OS to the boot.ini so I can boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/115934/46312 might try this

Answer (score 3):

Windows XP? Well...

This has been working since the early days of NT4:

- boot into your linux
- mount your Windows boot drive R/W to /media/fat
- perform `dd if=/dev/sdxY of=/media/fat/linux.bin bs=512 count=1` as root, replace `sdxY` with your linux partition
- edit your boot.ini to look like mine:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(5)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(5)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /NOEXECUTE=OPTIN /FASTDETECT
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional (Safe mode)" /BASEVIDEO /SOS
c:\CMDCONS\BOOTSECT.DAT="Microsoft Windows XP recovery console" /CMDCONS
c:\linux.bin="Grub (loader)"
```

Your results may vary: Grub2 might need downgrading to Grub 1.x for this to work.

Comment: Will this work if your Windows XP drive uses NTFS? (yes I still "use" XP...I'm more of a Mac + Linux user now but still have my old machine)

Comment: just try it - you are copying a file of 512 bytes to the root directory c:\.

If ntfs is not mountable from linux, copy it to a FAT-formatted usb-stick, then boot windows and copy it.

Comment: It did. I later realized that you are creating a file on the file system so once it's mounted it doesn't matter what the type is.

Comment: @aquaherd Thanks! I knew it worked like that but couldnt remember the details and spent like an hour googling superfluous approaches till I finally found your answer. Booting Haiku OS from NT loader to dualboot haiku and the original OS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't add Ubuntu to boot.ini.  You add a windows partition to grub.

If you must do it, it is described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/port25/archive/2006/10/13/http-port25-technet-com-archive-2006-10-12-windows-and-linux-integration-3a00-a-conversation-with-the-author-aspx.aspx) for implementations with bitlocker and TPM.

Comment: True.... But I would rather have Windows NT as my bootloader over grub

Answer (score 0):

I use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (because i have trouble installing GRUB on a EFI motherboard with fakeraid). There is a free version for noncommercial use at the bottom of the page.

As far as I remember, i set up the windows boot loader to chainload grub. There is a automatic method in EasyBCD, but it didn't work for me.

Instead I made it boot into a legacy GRUB with the following menu.lst:

```
# NeoSmart NeoGrub Bootloader Configuration File
#
# This is the NeoGrub configuration file, and should be located at C:\NST\menu.lst
# Please see the EasyBCD Documentation for information on how to create/modify entries:
# http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/

# Boot automatically after 0 secs.
timeout 0

# By default, boot the first entry.
default 0

title (hd0,4)
root (hd0,4)
kernel /vmlinuz root=UUID=5827fd40-9b04-4f8a-bb0f-df1612670d89 ro
initrd /initrd.img
```

Note:
(hd0,4) means that my root partition is on /dev/sda5.
UUID=X is the uuid of this volume. You can find this with `sudo blkid`.

Comment: -1: EasyBCD is Vista & 7 only. XP was asked instead.